# How to apply anvil ratelimit on postfix mynetworks host?

Tags: mta, rate-limiting, postfix-mta

We are using Postfix MTA as smarthost relay for our application servers. We are maintaining the access through "Mynetworks". We have list of IP addresses which are map to "Mynetworks".

Now days we are facing the issue of spamming / mass mailing though many application servers due to faulty scripting. Due to which our essential mails are getting stuck.

I have checked "Anvil rate limit" in postfix main.cf and following is tried,

```
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time = 600s
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_recipient_limit = 100
```

But it does not work with client defined "mynetworks" list, it excluded from anvil rate limiting.

Can anyone kindly help to achieve rate limit for mynetworks in postfix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slow directive to limit number of sended mail to a specific domain name.

In /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
slow    unix    -       -       n       -       5       smtp    
-o syslog_name=postfix-slow    
-o smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=3   
-o slow_destination_rate_delay=1 yahoo    unix - - n - 5       smtp    
-o syslog_name=postfix-slow    
-o smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=3    
-o slow_destination_rate_delay=1
```

In /etc/postfix/transport

```
yahoo.fr slow:
```

In /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
slow_destination_recipient_limit = 20
slow_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
```

Then do a postmap on the file and restart postfix

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Otherwise, you can install and configure postfwd which allow some sending restriction.

You can for example limite the number of email a user can send in one hour.